# How to copy and paste the last row until a certain date?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copy-paste

I am fairly newer to VBA. I took a class in college and that has been years now since using it. I am trying to copy the last row in a spreadsheet within columns A through S multiple times. I am needing to do this from the date specified in the last cell in column A until the date I specify in cell A1. This is going to be a report I update weekly is why I am trying to do this. I am needing to copy all of the formulas in the last row.

```
Public Sub CopyLastRow()
    
    ' Define the source sheet (no need to activate it)
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Steam Data")
    
    ' Find the last row in an specific column
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Range("A" & sourceSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the source range according to columns and last row
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A" & lastRow & ":S" & lastRow)
   
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim lcell As Long
   
   lcell = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   For x = lcell To x = Range("A1")
   
   If x < Range("A1") Then
    sourceRange.Copy
    sourceRange.Offset(1).PasteSpecial
    Else
    
    End If
   
  Next x
End Sub
```

I got this to work as a simple copy and paste. But once I did the if statement, it just does nothing with no error. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I am needing to copy all of the formulas in the last row."?

Comment: Please share some info on the destination worksheet: Is it in the same workbook? What is its name or index? Also, you're copying from the **source** worksheet's last row to the **source** worksheet's row after the last row multiple times overwriting each previous copy. Please explain where exactly do you want to copy to.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your last comment, the code below will do what you need. It can go into a module or the code section of the "Steam Data" worksheet. The "Steam Data" worksheet does not need to be active to run the code:

```
Public Sub CopyLastRow()

  Dim ws             As Worksheet, _
      rngSourceRange As Range, _
      rngTargetRange As Range, _
      lngLastRow     As Long, _
      lngRowsToAdd   As Long, _
      dteTargetDate  As Date, _
      dteLastDate    As Date

  ' Define the sheet we want to work with
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Steam Data")

  ' Establish the target date
  ' This will be your 'specified date' and can be a cell reference, a parameter
  ' passed into this procedure, or any other possible source. I have just hardcoded
  ' a date here as an example.
  dteTargetDate = #6/24/2023#

  With ws
    ' Determine the last row in Column A
    lngLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Make sure we have found a valid date. If not then show a message and get out.
    If IsDate(.Cells(lngLastRow, 1)) = False Then
      MsgBox "The last row does not contain a valid date. Process aborted."
      Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Calculate the number of rows (days) we need to add
    lngRowsToAdd = dteTargetDate - .Cells(lngLastRow, 1)

    ' Define the source and target ranges
    Set rngSourceRange = .Range("A" & lngLastRow)
    Set rngTargetRange = .Range("A" & lngLastRow & ":A" & lngLastRow + lngRowsToAdd)

    ' Copy the selected date to the target range with the 'Fill Series' option
    rngSourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=rngTargetRange

    ' Select and copy the columns from the last row that we want to repeat
    .Range("B" & lngLastRow & ":S" & lngLastRow).Copy

    ' Paste the rows
    .Paste Destination:=.Range("B" & lngLastRow + 1 & ":B" & lngLastRow + lngRowsToAdd)

  End With

  Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

For further info, I am not sure if you are familiar with the Record Macro option under the Developer Tab. This is a very useful tool for generating bare-bones code based on your keystrokes. The resulting code can be somewhat verbose with steps that may not be necessary but this can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy (Append) Last Row

[image]

**A Quick Fix (Preserving the Idea)**

```vb
Sub CopyLastRowQF()
    
    ' Define the source sheet (no need to activate it)
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Steam Data")
    
    ' Find the last row in a specific column
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Range("A" & sourceSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the source range according to columns and last row
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A" & lastRow & ":S" & lastRow)
   
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = sourceRange.Cells(1)
    
    Dim destRange As Range
    Set destRange = sourceRange.Offset(1)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim x As Long
    
    For x = lCell.Value + 1 To sourceSheet.Range("A1").Value
        sourceRange.Copy destRange
        Set destRange = destRange.Offset(1)
    Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**An Improvement**

```
Sub CopyLastRow()
    
    Const DATE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Steam Data").Columns("A:S")
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Columns(DATE_COLUMN) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in column
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Cells(DATE_COLUMN).Value - lCell.Value
        If rCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Rows already copied.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(lCell.EntireRow, .Cells)
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.Offset(1).Resize(rCount)
        srg.Copy drg
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The last part of your code needs to be adjusted by removing the `For ... Next` loop (which is improperly constructed to begin with) and removing the `If ... Else ... End If`. See my code snippet below:

```
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim lcell As Long
   
   lcell = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'   For x = lcell To 14   'x = Range("A1")
   
'   If x < Range("A1") Then
    sourceRange.Copy
    sourceRange.Offset(1).PasteSpecial
'    Else
    
'    End If
   
'  Next x
```

Comment: The worksheet is in the same workbook. Same sheet and everything. I am wanting to copy the last row of the spreadsheet to the row below it. And I want it to keep copying until a specified date. Basically automating the dragging down feature in excel.